# How to get the value of a an object in commonservice file to html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My **html**,

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group" show-errors>
        <label class="control-label" for="address">Address<span
                          class="error_red">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="contact_address" ng-change="vm.addGoogleAddress(
            'contact_address', vm.contact.addresses[0],'contact')" name="contact_address"
             ng-model="vm.contact.address" class="form-control gmaps"  
             required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <div ng-messages="vm.form.contactForm.contact_address.$error" role="alert">
          <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Address is required.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
        <input name="city" type="text" disabled="disabled" ng-model="cityname" 
                                               id="city" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

My **commonservice**,

```
 function addGoogleAddress(id, data, scope) {
     var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(id));
     google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
         var place = places.getPlace();
         if (place && place.address_components) {
             for (var i = 0; i < (place.address_components.length); i++) {
                 if (place.address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {
                     data.city.key = "1001";
                     data.city.name = place.address_components[i].long_name.toString();
                     $rootScope.cityname = data.city.name;
                 }
             }
         }
```

I want to display the `cityname` of my search results but I am getting it to my html,can anyone suggest help please.Thanks.

Comment: you cannot put `cityname` into `<input name="city" ng-model="cityname"/>`? Could you clarify what you want.

Comment: I want to get the city name value in my input tag and the cityname is in other controller and how can i get it.?

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you returned the value from the `addGoogleAddress` and used it, all inside the `controller` and assigned it there to `$scope` or `this` of the controller it self.

**Update**
Let's consider you have `myControler` like this:

```
//your controller
***.controller('myControler',['$scope','myService',...,function($scope,myService,...){
       $scope.cityName = myService.addGoogleAddress(...);
}]);
```

So you're using `myService` to add the address and get the value returned, and assigning it to `$scope`, now if you kept the html as it is it should work.

**P.S**:
If you didn't attach your controller with you UI do it like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-controller="myController">
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

you have incorrect number of arguments in `addeventlistener`:

```
addeventlistener.google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {...}
```

It should looks like that:

```
addeventlistener.addListener('place_changed', function() {...}
```

Example [how to use autocomplete can be seen here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

Just an example:

```
var autoCompletePlaces = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

autoCompletePlaces.addListener('place_changed', function() {          
   var place = autoCompletePlaces.getPlace();          
}
```